# Another brick in the JS wall

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function, object-literal

I must confess, JavaScript has -sometimes- strange behaviors.

```
var Npc = function() {
    this.name='Hello world';
}

Npc.attr='my new attribute';

console.log('>>>>'+Npc.attr);               // my new attribute
console.log('>>>>'+Npc.name);               // '' ????

var data = new Npc();

console.log('>>>>>' + data.attr);           // undefined
console.log('>>>>>' + data.name);           // Hello world
```

Sounds weird to me.
If I can understand the .name difference (instance vs literal), I cannot understand the "attr" behavior.

Is it a COW ? But with the node.js debugger I really see the attr atribute !?

Waw...

Comment: `attr` is a property of the constructor function, not of any of the instances created through it. The opposite is true for `name`.

Comment: What are you asking? This looks like correct behaviour to me. Perhaps you should read the documentation for object creation. "Javascript: the good parts" is a good book on the subject.

Comment: As a C++ programmer, I'm sorry this code sounds strange :) But now thanks to CONSTRUCTIVE answers, I understand.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the syntax. Apart from `if` statements and `for` loops, JavaScript has huge differences with C and friends.

Comment: Yes, the Npc function is an object in itself (instance of Function) and you can add members on an object instance on the fly. You can try running the code in Chrome and do a console.log(Npc) to see what kind of object Npc is. Because it's a function you can call it with `new` and use it as a constructor. More about constructors and prototype can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're coming from a class-keyword language like Java or C++, then this might help you.

In JavaScript a function can be used as a constructor for an object, as you did here:

```
var Npc = function() {
    this.name='Hello world';
}
var data = new Npc();
```

By way of *loose* analogy to a class-keyword language, the "name" property is an instance variable defined in a "class" called Npc. So the expression data.name is perfectly logical.

In JavaScript a function is also an object, which is how you used it here:

```
Npc.attr='my new attribute';
```

Again by way of *loose* analogy to a class-keyword language, Npc.attr is like a static class member. So attr is a member of Npc and not a member of any instance of Npc.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly normal.

```
var Npc = function() {
    this.name='Hello world';
}
```

is a function constructor,until you execute the function nothing happens and name doesnt exist,makes sense.

so at this point only attr is defined.

```
var data = new Npc();

console.log('>>>>>' + data.attr);           // undefined
console.log('>>>>>' + data.name);
```

`var data = new Npc();` returns a new object, makes sense because you are using `new`.

if you want to access attr you need to find a reference to Npc inside that new object

`data.constructor.attr` is where you will find attr

Edit

- little mistake on data.constructor.attr corrected

Comment: Ok, I see... But basically, what is the purpose of the constructor object ?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing strange here.
`attr` is the attribute of `Npc` function.
`name` is the attribute of object created when `Npc` is used as a constructor.
Therefore `Npc` function has no attribute `name` and object created by `Npc` has no attribute `attr`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse constructor function with objects it produces. If you want property to automatically propagate to all created objects - prototype it:

```
Npc.prototype.attr='my new attribute';

var data = new Npc();
console.log('>>>>>' + data.attr);           // 'my new attribute';
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st call you call `Npc()` directly (i.e not as a constructor). In this case the `this` inside the body of the function refers to the global object, which in your browser is the `window` object and in node is the `global` object. Either way, you assigned the `.name` property to the global object and thus you cannot see it as a property of the function object (don't forget that functions are ordinary objects as well in JavaScript and unless used with the `new` operator, they are not constructors)

In the 2nd case you actually use the function as a constructor since you use it in conjunction with the `new` operator. Here the `this.name=...` inside the body actually adds a `name` property to the newly instantiated object of type `Npc`. It is the `magic` of the `new` operator that gives the meaning of `"the instantiated object"` to the `"this"` keyword in the 2nd case.